# Tensorflow searches for wrong version of libcupti

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run an example of Tensorflow Summary (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py)

Then I got:

```
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:129] Couldn't open CUDA
> library libcupti.so.7.5. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
> /usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
> 2017-11-07 18:24:40.834087: F
> tensorflow/core/platform/default/gpu/cupti_wrapper.cc:59]
> Non-OK-status: ::tensorflow::Env::Default()->GetSymbolFromLibrary(
> GetDsoHandle(), kName, &f) status: Not found:
> /users/local/dnguyen/miniconda3/envs/RNN_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so:
> undefined symbol: cuptiActivityRegisterCallbackscould not find
> cuptiActivityRegisterCallbacksin libcupti DSO
```

I have CUDA 8.0 and 9.0 on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04), but Tensorflow tried to search for libcupti 7.5.

Could anyone help me solve this problem (without root access)?

Comment: Tensorflow is probably searching for CUDA  7.5 because that is what it was compiled against. There probably is no solution except to install the required version of CUDA

Comment: Thank you talonmies.
But I can run other codes with GPU without any problems. 
Is there any config/function to change the version of libcupti?

Comment: But your other codes were not compiled and linked against CUDA 7.5. The binary version of Tensorflow you have installed clearly was.

Comment: You can also try building tensorflow from source to use your latest cuda version. Or install cuda 7.5

Comment: It seems that installing CUDA 7.5 is the only solution.
Thank you